# Custom Like Action Rejected without reason

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

My request for approval for a custom open graph like action keeps getting rejected without any specific reason as to why it has been rejected:

> Your Action failed the criteria: We are unable to test this action
>   according to the usage instructions you provided. Pleas ensure the
>   steps you list are ones that a user must take in order to trigger the
>   action once the action goes live. Please provide thorough reproduction
>   instructions and link(s) to a specific URL where we can trigger the
>   action. You should also test your action to ensure you can
>   successfully publish actions back to the timeline of the test user
>   named Auth Dialog Preview User. Once you have made these changes,
>   re-submit your action.

I've supplied absolute idiot-proof instructions for testing the functionality and even tested them twice using the Open Graph Tester user for the app. I have honestly no idea what to change to get approved. Any ideas?

I'm also not sure what the following parts means for a pure AJAX application like mine:

> Please provide thorough reproduction instructions and link(s) to a
>   specific URL where we can trigger the action.

Does that mean the Facebook testers do not want to test the action using the User Interface of the Application but want to fire a http request at an URL which will obviously not work for a pure AJAX app.

Comment: _“I've supplied absolute idiot-proof instructions”_ – well, you know nature’s reaction to you making something idiot-proof … making better idiots …

Comment: This is so sad. Next rejection with same reason. I'm beginning to believe the testers are bots.

Comment: The FB testers do test your app using the app ui and they actually do not fire up an http request manually from what I know. What they need is a step by step click here then there. At least my actions were approved without providing anything more then that.

Comment: I also never used and heard or read about an Open Graph Tester before, I just published the actions on my own timeline (the timeline of the app admin) before submitting for approval. **If nothing else helps** a solution might be to delete the action, create it again, submit for approval, delete the app, create it again, submit for approval. Maybe you'll get a different tester.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not approve custom like actions any longer. Facebook recently introduced the "Built-in Like" as a built-in Open Graph action (see [blogpost](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/20/bringing-like-to-mobile/) and [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/)).

Comment: Yes I'm using the built-in like action. But when a non-admin user of the Facebook app attempts to invoke it, you'll receive an error stating that it needs to be approved first.

Comment: Your question said you were submitting a custom like action, not the built in - if so, Lego's answer is correct

Comment: @Igy Hi Igy. Thanks for your comment. It's true that I said custom like action. Right now I'm a bit confused how to handle the whole situation. My app is indeed using the built-in like action (posting to og.likes) but like I said, when I tried to use this code with a non-admin user of my app, I received an error stating that the action needs to be approved. That's why I thought I need to submit a  custom like action. In case you get a chance to take a look, here's the App's Facebook page: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/209093169210948/opengraph

Comment: I am currently facing this issue trying to submit a like action. It is the 7th times my app got rejected. From my latest submission, the clue I got, is to request the tester to test using the Facebook Test User. Hope me luck.